# webview only showing the first page

Tags: swift, webkit

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class FactsheetViewController: UIViewController {

    let webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(webView)
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://doc.morningstar.com/LatestDoc.aspx?clientid=stanlibpro&key=35d0c11e52f21126&documenttype=52&investmentidtype=1&ISIN=ZAE000084869") else {
            return
        }
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        webView.frame = view.bounds
    }

}
```

this code only shows the first page of the document. How do I show everything?

tried the code above and it only shows the first page whereas I was expecting to see the whole document

Comment: Even if you open it in Safari it will show only one page. Are you sure it should show more? Seems like the problem is not in WKWebView.

Comment: You mean Safari on the iPhone? If so, you are correct. I also tried Chrome and got the same thing. But if I try on Safari on my Mac it opens up the multiple pages. Does this mean no resolution for iPhone? Thanks.

Comment: It’s possible that this page is using some features which are not available on mobile browsers.